# Excel: Arrange Rows to Match Another Row

Tags: excel, sorting, rows

I have a database with a column A with some values, and then 2 additional columns: Column B contains a bunch values that will match the ones in column A, but are not in order. I also have a Column with information that pertains to that specific row, amnd would like it to stay in 'sync' with column B. For example:

```
| A | B | C |
  1   3   A
  2   1   F
  3   2   D
  4   5   R
  5   4   P
```

I'd like a way to sort it so my result would be:

```
| A | B | C |
  1   1   F
  2   2   D
  3   3   A
  4   4   P
  5   5   R
```

Is there a way to do this?

If possible, if there is no match, delete the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2007/2010, 
simply select the cell with the "B" in it and go to the Data tab along the top and click on the A to Z button which is near the middle of the data tab. As long as B & C are adjacent columns, they will sort according to your needs. Please Note, Column A must not be adjacent to the other 2, otherwise you would run through the same procedure above but you would highlight columns B and C and perform the same sort button steps. If it gives you a Sort Warning, click the "Continue with the Current Selection" radio button and OK.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know when you sorted that if there was a blank column in between that the other columns wouldn't be sorted. A simple sort and it put everything back to normal. Thank you.